# One-Hot Encode with Numerical Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Is it possible to one-hot encode a pandas dataframe by numerical values? It seems `get_dummies()` only works for string data.

For example, I'm hoping to do this:

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 1, 0, 2], 'B': [0, 0, 1, 0]})
>>> df
   A  B
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  0  1
3  2  0

>>> df_oh = SomeFunction(df)  # Does SomeFunction() exist?
>>> df_oh
   A_0 A_1 A_2 B_0 B_1
0  1   0   0   1   0
1  0   1   0   1   0
2  1   0   0   0   1
3  0   0   1   1   0
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) after converting `df` to string dtypes with [`DataFrame.astype()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), as follows:

```
pd.get_dummies(df.astype(str))
```

Result:

```
   A_0  A_1  A_2  B_0  B_1
0    1    0    0    1    0
1    0    1    0    1    0
2    1    0    0    0    1
3    0    0    1    1    0
```

Comment: The solution is hilariously simple ... the easiest ones to miss! lol - thanks for the help